# Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have a question about these two products. I have Visual Studio 2012 installed and I want to use a database, should I install SQL Server 2012? But SQL Server 2012 is using VS 2010's  shell. 
So I want to know, can I use VS 2012's shell to implement SQL Server's function? In this case, do I need to install SQL Server 2012?

Comment: "But SQL server 2012 is using VS 2010's shell" - where did you get that idea? And what do you mean by "shell", in this context?

Comment: When you start SQL server 2012, you will get a user interface just like VS 2010

Comment: @Tian When you start SQL Server 2012 by default you get nothing. It's a service. If you start the server binary manually, it runs in a console. If you start SQL Server Management Studio 2012, which is a different product, you get a user interface just like VS2010.

Comment: Yes, I am meaning when you using "SQL Server Management Studio 2012, you get a user interface just like VS2010". Since I have install VS 2012 already, I think it's redundant to have this VS 2010 interface. Can I install SQL Server 2012 without this interface and just use VS 2012's?@Ota.speot.is

Comment: The SQL Server Management Studio (based on the VS 2010 Shell) is an optional component when you install SQL Server 2012 - so yes, you can install SQL Server 2012 - the **database engine** - without installing the *redundant* VS 2010 shell of Management Studio - and just use the Visual Studio 2012 built-in tooling for SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

You can use whatever database you want. This is something completely separate from Visual Studio itself.

People have been using Visual Studio 2012 with Oracle, MySql, SQL Server 2000/2005/2008/2012 and others without issue.

Comment: Can I use sql server 2014 with VS 2012

Comment: Yes, you can. Why not try before asking?

Comment: I have already tried this but when I create a new database and right click on Table option, No add table option appears. Only Refresh and Properties Option appear.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue.

Comment: Do you mean to say permissions in propety?? Even if it was a permission issue, then the Add Table Option should appear in disabled state. But here it is not even showing the option.

Answer (score 0):

Both product are different you can use any database with your .NET application. Dont need to install only SQL Server for .NET Application.